# How to select form input based on label inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, wordpress

I have multiple forms that are dynamically created with different input names and id's. The only thing unique they will have is the inner HTML of the label. Is it possible to select the input via the label inner HTML with jQuery? Here is an **example of one** of my patient date of birth blocks, there are many and all unique except for innerHTML.

```
<div class="iphorm-element-spacer iphorm-element-spacer-text iphorm_1_8-element-spacer">
<label for="iphorm_081a9e2e6b9c83d70496906bb4671904150cf4b43c0cb1_8">events=Object { mouseover=[1], mouseout=[1]}handle=function()data=Object { InFieldLabels={...}}
    Patient DOB
    <span class="iphorm-required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="iphorm-input-wrap iphorm-input-wrap-text iphorm_1_8-input-wrap">
    <input id="iphorm_081a9e2e6b9c83d70496906bb4671904150cf4b43c0cb1_8" class="iphorm-element-text iphorm_1_8" type="text" value="" name="iphorm_1_8">events=Object { focus=[1], blur=[1], keydown=[1], more...}handle=function()
</div>
<div class="iphorm-errors-wrap iphorm-hidden"> </div>
```

This is in a Wordpress Plugin and because we are building to allow employees to edit their sites (this is actually a Wordpress Network), we do not want to alter the plugin if possible.
Note that the label "for" and the input "id" share the same dynamic key, so this might be a way to maybe get the id, but wanted to see if there is a shorter way of doing this.

Here I cleaned up what is likely not used...

```
<div>
<label for="iphorm_081a9e2e6b9c83d70496906bb4671904150cf4b43c0cb1_8">
    Patient DOB
    <span class="iphorm-required">*</span>
</label>
<div>
    <input id="iphorm_081a9e2e6b9c83d70496906bb4671904150cf4b43c0cb1_8">
</div>
```

Comment: `Note that the label "for" and the input "id" share the same dynamic key, so this might be a way to maybe get the id, but wanted to see if there is a shorter way of doing this` Try that and if it doesn't work, post the code or possibly even a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net we can have a look at then. On a general note, while inline script works it is better if you can move the script into a separate file or at least into a `<script>` section. It will make it easier later to find , debug and update code.

Comment: You are adding some sort of JavaScript mark up into the HTML? Why don;t you added classes and select them?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Wahl The script inline is actually generated by the Plugin and I don't want to touch it so that any updates on their end goes through clean. I actually want to use jQuery selectors to clean up the input. For example, I want to add a date picker and add some masks just to make the form user friendly. Unfortunately, the form is not programmer friendly.

Comment: Those are some the hugest classes and ids ever. WoW. Although you mentioned you want to edit the plugin it would be easy to just a unique id to the parent div

Comment: @Pablo Yeah, after building multiple forms for our reps I was very excited about the project until I decided to clean up the input and noticed the id/class structure. Being so large is weird then on top of it they did not design for a network site.

Comment: @Shane i think you should switch to another form generator while you can, never is too late. Or you should code then your self, is not that complicated, then you just reuse your code for future projects

Comment: @Pablo Unfortunately this is out of my control. Wordpress was requested by the department manager, then the form plugin was chosen by my boss due to it's drag/drop features in admin. I have to run with it. With more time, I might consider re-writing some of the code, but this looks to be still actively developed and could be updated without my involvement. That would over-ride any code I apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select the `Patient DOB` labels, then find the related input.

```
$('label:contains("Patient DOB")').parent('div').find('input');
```

This assumes that the `label` and `input` are wrapped in the same `div` and may not work if more than one pair is in the same `div`. At least the first part will get you the labels that contain `Patient DOB`, then you can adjust the later parts to find the correct input element.

For more help on jquery selectors, see the [API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAfmX/) demonstrating this.

Comment: Nice! That is what I am looking for, a way to use a simple selector without writing a long conditional statement. Let me test this out and if it works your answer is golden!

Comment: Still working on this, I ran a  $('label:contains("Patient DOB")').parent('div').find('input').append('<span>Test</span>'); with no luck.

Comment: That appends an element inside the input tag. The `input` element should be empty, which is probably why nothing is displayed. See jsFiddle added to answer for demo.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Not conventional (my forms) as I like, but your fix helps keep it simply. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var getForm = function(labelInnerHtml) {
    var $labels = jQuery('label');
    $labels.each(function() {
       if (jQuery(this).html() == labelInnerHtml) {
            var for_id = jQuery(this).attr('for');
            return jQuery('#'+for_id);
        }
    });
    return [];
};​​
```

Comment: Just note, I am looking for "Patient DOB" in this case, not "iphorm_081a9e2e6b9c83d70496906bb4671904150cf4b43c0cb1_8" because that is what is NOT unique to all forms, due to the design of this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The class iphorm_1_8 on the input is unique for each form element. So it's simple.

```
$('.iphorm_1_8');
```